# Поиск elasticsearch не ищет символ &

Tags: поиск, elasticsearch

Не ищет символ &

```
"name": {
    "type": "text",
    "analyzer": "whitespace",
    "search_analyzer": "whitespace"
},
```

Comment: попробуйте заменить `&` на `%26`

Comment: @de_frag при маппинге или при поиске?